# after multiple search filter wont work in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-filtering

I am searching in grid with multiples columns, Whenever i searched any value multiples times in multiple columns,search filters won't work after repeated search attempt.

Here is my filter code

```
export class FilterBy {
    public filterData(items: any, filterData: any): any {
        var result: any;
        if (filterData === undefined) {
            return items;
        }
        filterData.forEach(function (value, key) {

            if (isNaN(value)) {
                items = items.filter((item: any) => {
                    if (item[key].toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase()))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                })
            }
            else {
                items = items.filter((item: any) => {
                    if (item[key].toString().includes(value))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                })
            }    
        });
        return items;
    }
}
```

And here is my component code.

```
if ((filters === undefined || filters == '') && this.filterData.has(columnName)) {
    this.filterData.delete(columnName);
}

var obj: FilterBy = new FilterBy();
var result = obj.filterData(this.data, this.filterData);
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: Before helping you : can't you use a pipe ? It would be easier

Comment: okay sure.. I will try it ..